# crud trigger next button calendar

Tags: codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

I have a site developed in crud with codeigniter.
I would when I enter into a determinate function in my view to trigger the button dhx_cal_next_button that goes on of a week for example.
I have tried but nothing succeed:

```
$('.dhx_cal_next_button').trigger('click');
```

I have seen that into the file dhtmlxscheduler.js there is this code (I have cut more code out this function):

```
scheduler._click={
    dhx_cal_next_button:function(dummy,step){
        scheduler.setCurrentView(scheduler.date.add( //next line changes scheduler._date , but seems it has not side-effects
            scheduler.date[scheduler._mode+"_start"](scheduler._date),(step||1),scheduler._mode));
    }
};
```

How can I simulate the click event on this button? 
Thanks